# regex to print out lines after hostname until delemiter

Tags: python, regex, list

i have a list which goes as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.mydomain.de                         UP                            Thu May  8 09:10:57 2014
              HTTPS                    OK                            Thu May  8 09:10:08 2014
              HTTPS-Cert         OK                            Thu May  8 09:10:55 2014
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.someotherdomain.de                         UP                            Thu May  8 09:09:17 2014
              HTTPS                    OK                            Thu May  8 09:09:30 2014
              HTTPS-Cert         OK                            Thu May  8 09:11:10 2014
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.somedifferentdomain.at                         UP                            Thu May  8 09:08:47 2014
              HTTPS                    OK                            Thu May  8 09:10:26 2014
              HTTPS-Cert         OK                            Thu May  8 09:11:13 2014
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.foobladomain.de                         UP                            Thu May  8 09:09:17 2014
              HTTPS                    OK                            Thu May  8 09:09:30 2014
              HTTPS-Cert         OK                            Thu May  8 09:11:08 2014
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.snafudomain.at                         UP                            Thu May  8 09:09:17 2014
              HTTP                     OK                            Thu May  8 09:09:42 2014
              HTTPS                    OK                            Thu May  8 09:10:10 2014
              HTTPS-Cert         OK                            Thu May  8 09:10:09 2014
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
www.lolnotanotherdomain.de                         UP                            Thu May  8 09:06:57 2014
              HTTP                     OK                            Thu May  8 09:11:10 2014
              HTTPS                    OK                            Thu May  8 09:11:16 2014
              HTTPS-Cert         OK                            Thu May  8 09:11:10 2014
```

and i have a function which takes the hostname as parameter and prints it out:

```
please enter hostname to search for: www.snafudomain.at
www.snafudomain.at                         UP                            Thu May  8 09:09:17 2014
```

but what i want to archive is that the following lines after the hostname are printed out until the delimiter line "-----" the function i right now looks like this:

```
def getChecks(self,hostname):
    re0 = "%s" % hostname
    mylist = open('myhostlist', 'r')
    for i in mylist:
        if re.findall("^%s" % re0, str(i)):
        print i
        else:
        continue
```

is there some easy way to do this? If something is unclear please comment. Thanks in advance

### edit

to clarify the output should look like this:

```
www.mydomain.de                         UP                            Thu May  8 09:10:57 2014
              HTTPS                    OK                            Thu May  8 09:10:08 2014
              HTTPS-Cert         OK                            Thu May  8 09:10:55 2014
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

just want to print out the lines from the searched domain name till the line with only minuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about not using regex at all?

```python
def get_checks(self, hostname):
    record = False
    with open('myhostlist', 'r') as file_h:
        for line in file_h:
            if line.startswith(hostname):
                record = True
                print(line)
            elif line.startswith("---"):
                record = False
                print(line)
            elif record:
                print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def get_checks(hostname):
    pattern = re.compile(r"{}.*?(?=---)".format(re.escape(hostname)), re.S)
    with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
        return re.search(pattern, in_file.read())

print get_checks("www.snafudomain.at").group()
```

This will returns all the lines starting with `www.snafudomain.at` till it finds `---`. The pattern generated will be like this

```
www\.snafudomain\.at.*?(?=---)
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eU6yI7)

We use `re.escape` because your hostname has `.` in it. Since `.` has special meaning in the Regular Expressions, we just want the RegEx engine to treat `.` as literal dot.

Comment: looks goot but not exactly what i have meant. I have edited my post to clarify